# how to prevent two same useState hooks from being triggered on one click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have 2 components with similar logic, they both conditionally display a message, based on the local state from useState hook and two props from the redux state. However, the problem occurs when I click on the ConnectedPasswordChange button - I see two messages, one from its own component and one from ProfileForm. Any idea how to get rid of that? Does it have something to do with event bubbling?

```
const ConnectedPasswordChange = (): Node => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const isUpdating = useSelector(state => state.user.isUpdating);
  const updateError = useSelector(state => state.user.updateError);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const { currentPassword, newPassword } = passwordDetails;
    dispatch(passwordUpdateRequested(currentPassword, newPassword));
    setSubmitted(true);
    setTimeout(() => setSubmitted(false), 5000);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PasswordChange passwordDetails={passwordDetails} onPasswordChange={setPasswordDetails} />
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Form.Button secondary>Button</Form.Button>
      </div>
      {submitted && !isUpdating && !updateError && <Message positive content="Success" />}
    </Form>
  );
};
```

ConnectedPasswordChange is used in ProfileForm component that is using the same logic

```
const ProfileForm = ({ id, user: initialUser, locations, isUpdating, updateError, onSubmit }: Props): Node => {

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    onSubmit(id);
    setSubmitted(true);
    setTimeout(() => setSubmitted(false), 5000);
  };

  return (
    <Segment className="my-profile-main-container">
      <Title />
      <Divider />
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <PersonalDetails personalDetails={user} onPersonalDetailsChange={handleDetailsChange} />
        <Divider />
        <BankDetails bankDetails={user} onBankDetailsChange={handleDetailsChange} />
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <Form.Button secondary>Button</Form.Button>
        </div>
        {submitted && !isUpdating && !updateError && <Message positive content={t("updateSucceeded")} />}
        <Divider />
        <ConnectedPasswordChange />
      </Form>
    </Segment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try to use e.stopPropagation() on your handleSubmit function inside ConnectedPasswordChange

Answer (score 0):

It's not typical to nest forms, so yes it appears if you submit an inner form, it also bubbles and triggers a submit event on the outer form component as well. To prevent this you can use [`Event.prototype.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```js
const ProfileForm = () => {
  const tableRef = React.useRef();
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    tableRef.current.insertRow().append('ProfileForm submitted');
  };
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>ProfileForm</legend>
        <ConnectedPasswordChange />
        <input type="submit" />
        <table ref={tableRef} />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
};

const ConnectedPasswordChange = () => {
  const tableRef = React.useRef();
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // important! without this, ProfileForm will submit as well
    tableRef.current.insertRow().append('ConnectedPasswordChange submitted');
  };
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>ConnectedPasswordChange</legend>
        <input type="submit" />
        <table ref={tableRef} />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ProfileForm />, document.querySelector('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Note that the resulting HTML is not valid, as `<form>` elements [are not allowed to contain other `<form>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). If you try to statically render this HTML using a server-side React framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) you may find that the document may not end up as you expect:

```js
// the inner <form> was stripped from the markup
console.log(document.getElementById('ConnectedPasswordChange'));
console.log(document.querySelector('main').outerHTML);
```

```html
<main>
  <form id="ProfileForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>ProfileForm</legend>
      <form id="ConnectedPasswordChange">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>ConnectedPasswordChange</legend>
          <input type="submit" />
          <table></table>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <input type="submit" />
      <table></table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```